# Rust Serialization Lib Minting NFT - Missing Key Witnesses Error on Submission

Tags: nft, cardano-serialization-lib, minting

I am running into an error with the CSL Rust Lib when submitting a minting NFT tx.  I am following a minimal example in JS https://gist.github.com/lovalabs/83d08796ab9ff65cbf188fbca8d03343 as a guide for the RUST library.  I receive the following error when attempting to submit the built tx via the cardano-CLI:

```
Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (MissingScriptWitnessesUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash "d47c1b40ca47ac8f1b0c0f01941acbc634dbd5896239a2ade9548557"]))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (CollectErrors [NoRedeemer (Minting (PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "d47c1b40ca47ac8f1b0c0f01941acbc634dbd5896239a2ade9548557"})),NoWitness (ScriptHash "d47c1b40ca47ac8f1b0c0f01941acbc634dbd5896239a2ade9548557")]))))])
```

My RUST declarations are as follows:

Policy NativeScripts

```
 //Initialize 'NativeScript' for NFT Policy 
    let mut native_scripts = NativeScripts::new();
    let script_public_key = NativeScript::new_script_pubkey(&ScriptPubkey::new(&policy_public_key_hash));

    //Initialize 'TimelockExpiry' and 'NativeScript' 
    let timelock_expiry_fmt = TimelockExpiry::new_timelockexpiry(&BigNum::from_str("59634480").unwrap());
    let script_timelock = NativeScript::new_timelock_expiry(&timelock_expiry_fmt);

    //Add Public Key and Timelock 'NativeScript' to Collection of 'NativeScripts'    
    native_scripts.add(&script_public_key);
    native_scripts.add(&script_timelock);

    //Initialize 'ScriptAll' type of 'NativeScript' & Add 'NativeScripts' with script public key and timelock expiry
    let policy_script = NativeScript::new_script_all(&ScriptAll::new(&native_scripts));

    //Initialize 'PolicyID', 'AssetName', and 'Amount'
    let asset_name = AssetName::new("Rust-CSL-NFT-Mint".as_bytes().to_vec()).unwrap();
    let amount = Int::new(&BigNum::from_str("1").unwrap());
```

Builder & Witnesses

```
//Add 'NativeScript', 'AssetName', 'Amount' (Int), and 'TransactionOutputAmountBuilder' to 'TransactionBuilder'
    tx_builder.add_mint_asset_and_output_min_required_coin(&policy_script, &asset_name, amount, &tx_output_amount_builder).unwrap();    

    //Set 'ttl' for 'Transaction'
    tx_builder.set_ttl_bignum(&BigNum::from_str("59634480").unwrap());

    //Add 'TransactionInputs'
    tx_builder.add_key_input(&input_public_key_hash, &tx_input_1, &tx_value);

    //Add Change Wallet
    tx_builder.add_change_if_needed(&addr_1).unwrap();

    //Build Transaction
    let transaction = tx_builder.build_tx().unwrap();

    //Set 'TransactionWitnessSet'
    let mut vkey_witnesses: Vkeywitnesses = Vkeywitnesses::new();
    let tx_hash = hash_transaction(&transaction.body());
    let vkey_witness_wallet = make_vkey_witness(&tx_hash, &input_private_key);
    let vkey_witness_policy = make_vkey_witness(&tx_hash, &policy_private_key);
    vkey_witnesses.add(&vkey_witness_wallet);
    vkey_witnesses.add(&vkey_witness_policy);
    let mut tx_witness_set = TransactionWitnessSet::new();
    tx_witness_set.set_vkeys(&vkey_witnesses);
    tx_witness_set.set_native_scripts(&native_scripts);
    
    //Sign Transaction
    let signed_transaction = Transaction::new(&transaction.body(), &tx_witness_set, None);
```

I hope that I am missing something simple here.  I have added the input and policy keys as witnesses and I have added the policy nativescripts to the tx_witness_set but have not had any success resolving the error.  There is more than enough Test Ada in the utxo and I understand that the `add_mint_asset_and_output_min_required_coin()` handles the min fee and defines the PolicyID associated with the tx.  Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated as I have not found any rust tutorials or examples for the CSL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete the NFT Minting successfully following a different JS demo as a reference https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/doc/getting-started/minting-nfts.md There are zero RUST examples online for using the Cardano Serialization Library so I will post the code for any future Rustaceans in search of help.

```
//------------------------------------------NFT Policy------------------------------------------
    //Initialize 'NativeScript' for NFT Policy 
    let mut native_scripts = NativeScripts::new();

    //let script_public_key = NativeScript::new_script_pubkey(&ScriptPubkey::new(&policy_public_key_hash));
    let policy_addr = BaseAddress::new(NetworkInfo::testnet().network_id(), &StakeCredential::from_keyhash(&policy_public_key_hash), &StakeCredential::from_keyhash(&policy_public_key_hash)).to_address();
    let policy_keyhash = BaseAddress::from_address(&policy_addr).unwrap().payment_cred().to_keyhash().unwrap();
    let key_hash_script = NativeScript::new_script_pubkey(&ScriptPubkey::new(&policy_keyhash));
    native_scripts.add(&key_hash_script);

    //Initialize 'TimelockExpiry' and 'NativeScript' 
    let timelock_expiry_fmt = TimelockExpiry::new_timelockexpiry(&BigNum::from_str("59634480").unwrap());
    let script_timelock = NativeScript::new_timelock_expiry(&timelock_expiry_fmt);
    native_scripts.add(&script_timelock);

    let mint_script = NativeScript::new_script_all(&ScriptAll::new(&native_scripts));

    let addr = BaseAddress::new(NetworkInfo::testnet().network_id(), &StakeCredential::from_keyhash(&input_public_key_hash), &StakeCredential::from_keyhash(&input_public_key_hash)).to_address();
    let private_key_hash = BaseAddress::from_address(&addr).unwrap().payment_cred().to_keyhash().unwrap();
```

```
 //--------------------------------------Transaction Builder--------------------------------------
    //Initialize 'TransactionBuilder' from 'TransactionBuilderConfig'
    let mut tx_builder = TransactionBuilder::new(&tx_builder_config);

    //Add 'TransactionInputs'
    tx_builder.add_key_input(&private_key_hash, &tx_input_1, &tx_value);

    //Initialize 'PolicyID', 'AssetName', and 'Amount'
    let asset_name = AssetName::new("Rust-CSL-NFT-Mint".as_bytes().to_vec()).unwrap();
    let amount = Int::new(&BigNum::from_str("1").unwrap());
```

```
//------------------------------------Outputs (Wallet Addresses)---------------------------------
     //Initialize 'TransactionOutputAmountBuilder' from 'TransactionOutputBuilder'
     let tx_output_builder = TransactionOutputBuilder::new();     
     let tx_output_amount_builder = tx_output_builder.with_address(&addr).next().unwrap();

    //Add 'NativeScript', 'AssetName', 'Amount' (Int), and 'TransactionOutputAmountBuilder' to 'TransactionBuilder'
    tx_builder.add_mint_asset_and_output_min_required_coin(&mint_script, &asset_name, amount, &tx_output_amount_builder).unwrap();  

    //------------------------------------------NFT METADATA------------------------------------------
    //Generate Policy ID and Metadata
    let _policy_id = hex::encode(mint_script.hash().to_bytes());
    let metadata_input_string = String::from("{\"[d47c1b40ca47ac8f1b0c0f01941acbc634dbd5896239a2ade9548557]\": {\"[Rust-CSL-NFT-Mint]\": {\"name\": \"Rust-CSL-NFT-Mint-Example\",\"description\": \"Rust CSL NFT\",\"image\": \"bafkreibsko7qh472qkkwmk6fcfhbrhiuvzna5fkqzvak7gvgqosasaubi4\",\"type\": \"image\"}}}");
    let metadata = encode_json_str_to_metadatum(metadata_input_string.clone(), csl::metadata::MetadataJsonSchema::BasicConversions).expect("encode failed");
    let metadata_output_string = decode_metadatum_to_json_str(&metadata, csl::metadata::MetadataJsonSchema::BasicConversions).expect("decode failed");
    //println!("{}", metadata_output_string);

    //Set 'ttl' for 'Transaction'
    tx_builder.set_ttl_bignum(&BigNum::from_str("59634480").unwrap());

    //Set NFT 'MeatadatumLabel' (721)
    tx_builder.add_json_metadatum(&BigNum::from_str("721").unwrap(),metadata_output_string).unwrap();

        //Add Change Wallet
    tx_builder.add_change_if_needed(&addr).unwrap();

    let tx_body = tx_builder.build().unwrap();
    let tx_hash = hash_transaction(&tx_body);
    //println!("{:?}", hex::encode(&tx_hash.to_bytes()));

    let mut tx_witness_set = TransactionWitnessSet::new();
    let mut vkey_witnesses: Vkeywitnesses = Vkeywitnesses::new();
    vkey_witnesses.add(&make_vkey_witness(&tx_hash, &policy_private_key));
    vkey_witnesses.add(&make_vkey_witness(&tx_hash, &input_private_key));
    tx_witness_set.set_vkeys(&vkey_witnesses);
    tx_witness_set.set_native_scripts(&native_scripts);

    let mut witness_scripts = NativeScripts::new();
    witness_scripts.add(&mint_script);
    tx_witness_set.set_native_scripts(&witness_scripts);

    let unsigned_transaction = tx_builder.build_tx().unwrap();

    let signed_transaction = Transaction::new(&unsigned_transaction.body(), &tx_witness_set, unsigned_transaction.auxiliary_data());
```

https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/address.html?address=addr_test1qpus2z0svc6n6dv64cryzdc695430lpkqvk5dsp6lltn8zteq5ylqe34856e4tsxgym35tftzl7rvqedgmqr4l7hxwys99g6gw

Hope this is useful for someone, I spent awhile searching for RUST examples and came up empty-handed.